# Both side of my mesh are not moving independently after fixing bone naming conventions

Tags: mesh, bones, mirror

Somewhere along my animation process, I realized that my bones were not named properly when I "mirrored" them. (Instead of Upper Arm.L and Upper Arm.R, I had somehow copied it as Upper Arm.L and Upper Arm.R.001). When I was animating my model, I realized this and went to go fix the names of the bones (Now Upper Arm.L and Upper Arm.R, etc.) so I could flip my poses for making a walking animation. Success! I was able to flip the pose. Then, when I went into pose mode to create the next pose of my animation, the left and right legs were not moving independently anymore, and they are now both moving when I try to pose the model, no matter which IK bone I select. See this inserted GIF below:

[image: Independent movement issue.]

Is there an easy fix for this? Or am I missing something on a larger scale when I tried to fix my previous error?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your mirror is still enabled, try disabling that. As you can see in the upper righthand corner of the 3D viewport.